# Widget title font and size won't change

Tags: css

I'm using a popular posts widget on blogger and I can't get the font to change. Im using a custom font I have everywhere else on my blog. I used this css as a temporary solution

```
.sidebar h2.title, .sidebar h2 {
display: none;
}
```

this gets rid of the title, but now I'd like the title back and using:

```
.sidebar h2.title, .sidebar h2 {
font-family: raleway;
}
```

doesn't work. I've also tried with the widget Id and some other variations..

```
.popularposts1 {
font-family: raleway
}
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated :)

Edit *

I've also tried

```
.popularposts .widget-title {
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
```

I'm sure it's something along these lines but i just can't figure out where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the font (if you haven't) and also use quotes around the `font-family` declaration.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);
    .your-class {
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    }
```

```html
<div class="your-class">
  This is in a different font.
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not working :/ I've also already imported the font. I can't figure out why it would work with display:none; and not font-family :(

Comment: Are you using an old version of Internet Explorer? IE 8 and before is very buggy. (It works for me)